# changing html element value

Tags: html, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to prompt for a value that will replace the value for "data-amount"

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="http://249lease.webs.com/" class="dwolla_button" data-name="Lease" data-desc="Payments" data-amount="5" data-shipping="0"              data-tax="0" data-guest-checkout="true" data-key="sHqCOc31Vh3JiAsPhBfEk5f4D9bAWKLzwaT06ah3Aw65i0gkZl">Bank Account (25¢)</a>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dwolla.com/scripts/button.min.js"> </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've added

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementByClass("dwolla_button")[0].setAttribute("data-amount", "43");
</script>
```

and tried the whole thing in this script below with no success any ideas?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="http://249lease.webs.com/" class="dwolla_button" data-name="Lease" data-desc="Payments" data-amount="5" data-shipping="0"              data-tax="0" data-guest-checkout="true" data-key="sHqCOc31Vh3JiAsPhBfEk5f4D9bAWKLzwaT06ah3Aw65i0gkZl">Bank Account (25¢)</a>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          document.getElementByClass("dwolla_button")[0].setAttribute("data-amount", "43");
        </script>  

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dwolla.com/scripts/button.min.js"> </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your method from getElementByClassName to [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName)

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("dwolla_button")[0].setAttribute("data-amount", "43");
```

Comment: how might you make it so that the value must be entered by the user?